# How can I set the Customer Lookup to Contact instead of Account in CRM 2011 UR 12

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

The following code helps me to set the Customer Lookup to Contact instead of Account.

```
document.getElementById("customerid").setAttribute("defaulttype", "2");
```

It is so in IE, but how can I do this for Chrome?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you are on Polaris here for the multi browser support.

That isn't supported JavaScript, so I wouldn't expect it to work in Chrome. As far as I know there is currently no supported way to set the lookup to default to a particular entity (though I would be very pleased to be proved wrong here).

I only supported JavaScript functions are in the Xrm.Page API.

Relevant article: [Use JavaScript with Microsoft Dynamics CRM - Write JavaScript for Multiple Browsers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh771584.aspx#BKMK_WriteJavaScriptForMutlipleBrowsers).